# First Dad - How to make her understand that I am DAD

Tags: toddler, language-development, speech, first-time

I am first time parents and my daughter is 22 months, she is turning 2 in 60 days. My concern is she is not responding to her name, sometime she do, like once or twice in a day. Her hearing is fine. She do little eye contact (not much is our culture so I believe it might be in the genes). She do play with different toys, make different noises. When she see apple picture, she can call it apple and same for ball, she do call mummy daddy but she do not call us as mummy daddy. She just say words. When she need something she hold my finger and take me there. How should I make her understand that I am her father or call me dad. Is it normal not to recognize at this age ? Though she is attach to me, she looks for me when I am not around.

Comment: Have you talked to your pediatrician about this?  There are screeners they can use to evaluate various developmental conditions, autism, etc., that take as input things like what you described (can she respond to her name, does she randomly talk to you about things, can you point at something and she looks at it, that sort of thing).  That's the most important thing - make sure there's nothing concerning that you might need specialist help to address, especially as the earlier you do catch something the better you can help her, long term.  But the pediatrician is the best person to say.

Comment: she do watch the stuff when I point her towards something, she never randomly talk to me about anything, she has eye contact but still doesnt respond to her name, sometime she do but mostly not. She used to have lot of screen time last year it might be 6-7 hours a day. We did talk to her pediatrician but they are busy due to covid, she ask the same question and then next appt too late

Comment: I am not a doctor and medical advice is off topic here. But I highly recommend discussing your question with a pediatrician. Have you at least talked about this with other parents? What did they say?

Comment: Well different parents saying different things like every child is different. Like my nephew she started to walk in her 20month but started speaking in her 12months.

Comment: I'm a physician, and I second @TimurShtatland comment. I have seen thousands of kids during my career, and it is true, as you say, that kids are different and this might be nothing. That doesn't mean that different shouldn't be evaluated, because sometimes, different needs specific treatment to progress more "normally" (in the strictest sense of the word, i.e. like most kids her age.) You asked a question, and parents are telling you to discuss this with her pediatrician. That is the very best advice you're going to get. Don't take "too busy" for an answer. Or, find someone who isn't too busy.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR: I highly recommend discussing your question with a pediatrician.**

Also, please do see the comment above from *anongoodnurse*.

**DETAILS:**

*While you are waiting for the appointment with the pediatrician who is not "too busy" (huh?) to see your child*, you may find the info below useful. The United States Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) have useful checklists here: ["CDC’s Developmental Milestones"](https://www.cdc.gov/ncbddd/actearly/milestones/index.html).

Note that we ourselves have **always** taken our kids to the pediatrician for periodic screening (the so-called "well visits"). We learned a ton from the doctors. We only used the checklists for additional general education, not as a substitute for the screenings by the doctor. Sorry if I sound like a broken record. :)

The ["Important Milestones: Your Child By Eighteen Months"](https://www.cdc.gov/ncbddd/actearly/milestones/milestones-18mo.html) checklist is too long even for my typical answer. I will just quote this stern warning from the end of the page:

> **Concerned About Your Child’s Development? Act Early.**
>
> Tell your child’s
> doctor or nurse if you notice any of these signs of possible
> developmental delay for this age and ask for a developmental
> screening. Talk with someone in your community who is familiar with
> services for young children in your area, such as your state’s public
> early intervention program. For more information, [visit our “If
> You’re Concerned” web
> page](https://www.cdc.gov/ncbddd/actearly/concerned.html) or call
> **1-800-CDC-INFO**.
>
> The American Academy of Pediatrics recommends that children be
> screened for general development using standardized, validated tools
> at 9, 18, and 30 months and for autism at 18 and 24 months or whenever
> a parent or provider has a concern. Ask your child’s doctor about your
> child’s developmental screening.
>
> “Learn the Signs. Act Early.” materials are not a substitute for
> standardized, validated developmental screening tools.